# UIImageView - class never called

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, storyboard

I'm using StoryBoard to create my app.

I created a custom class of `UIImageView`. In StoryBoard I added a `UIImageView` in my view and linked it to my custom class.

My class is never called and my imageview is not displayed. Did i miss something? Thanks.

Comment: Did u check that you have correctly referred to your custom class in IB? - this has to be done in the identity inspector section custom class.

Comment: yes i have already checked this.

Comment: did u declare your property to reference the image as an IBoutlet?

Comment: you need to see a little round on the right side of ur declaration that  tell u that the connection is made.

Comment: @tiguero, when i click the little round on the right side of my declarataion, i go my custom class. but i didn't declre my property as an IBOutlet. Why do i need to do this?

Comment: IBoutlet is a way to link ur UI with ur implementation so there is a good chance that this is ur problem